# Flutter define Theme of `SliverAppBar`

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a `SliverAppBar` instead of a normal `AppBar` but I couldn't find a way to define an App wide theme for a `SliverAppBar`.
Below is an excerpt of my ThemeData with the style of the AppBar:

*theme.dart*

```
appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
  elevation: 0.0,
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf7fbff),
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: Color(0xFF0B0C10),
  ),
),
```

I would be interested to know if it's possible to also theme the `SliverAppBar` the same as a normal `AppBar`?